# My component in Vuejs isn't rendering in my Blade View

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-blade

My Vuejs component isn't being rendered in my blade view. What am I doing wrong?

My component is called "star-rating".

**Blade view**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        **<star-rating></star-rating>**
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Rating - statistics
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @if(auth()->check())
            <form method="post" action="{{ route('review.store') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <h5>Form title</h5> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="headline"><strong>Headline</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="headline" id="headline" placeholder="Review title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="headline"><strong>Rating</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rating" id="rating" placeholder="A number from 1 - 5">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="headline"><strong>Description</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Tell us about your experience">
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product->id }}">

                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
            </form>
        @else
            <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Write a review</a>
        @endif
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <ul>
            @forelse($product->reviews as $review)
            <li>{{ $review->headline }}</li>
            @empty
                <h6>There are not reviews for this product</h6>
            @endforelse
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@section('scripts')
  <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
@endsection
```

In the Vuejs, I have imported package for creating a rating system. If you would like to see the docs, are these [Star Rating System Vuejs](https://github.com/craigh411/vue-star-rating)

**Vuejs File**

```
import VueStarRating from 'vue-star-rating'

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


Vue.component('example-component', 
require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

Vue.component('star-rating', VueStarRating);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

I'm getting this two errors:

1) **[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.**

2) **CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token**

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No, the console is not showing errors that's why is hard for me finding the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was solved in two steps:

1) run: npm run dev

2) run: npm run watch

Now, it works

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you are compiling the script that you wrote in **app.js** with

```
npm run watch
```

command.

2) I dont see any div element which has **#app** id. You are saying that I will target **#app** element with

```
const app = new Vue({ <br>
    el: '#app' 
});
```

But you dont have any. Try to put it:

`<div class="container" id="app">`

Comment: I did what you say, now it's throwing me these two errors

Comment: Look at my question, I edited it, and wrote the errors

Comment: Can you try to write `import Vue from 'vue'` after `window.Vue = require('vue');`

Comment: I solved it adding this meta tag <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">